# Avoid overwriting xlsx file in Apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache poi to write in to an excel and given download option to that file. But each time when I download, it's overwriting the existing file and even file size is also increasing.

I want to create a new file by same name each time.

```
ServletContext servletContext = httpSession.getServletContext()
String absolutePathToIndexJSP = servletContext.getRealPath("/") + "File/filename.xlsx
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(absolutePathToIndexJSP));
System.out.println("file path : " + absolutePathToIndexJSP);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setAlignment(XSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
row.setHeight((short) 2000);
XSSFCell r1c = row.createCell(0);
row.removeCell(r1c);

r1c.setCellValue("Ptoto");

for (int s = 0; s < arrayJson.length(); s++) {
    System.out.println(s);

    int imageCount = s + 1;
    System.out.println(imageCount);
    String absolutePathToImage = servletContext.getRealPath("/") + "imgData/" + imageCount + ".jpg";

    System.out.println("writing image");
    System.out.println("path : " + absolutePathToImage);
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(absolutePathToImage);

    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);

    inputStream.close();
    CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
    Drawing drawing = null;
    drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

    row.removeCell(r1c);
    anchor.setCol1(s + 1);
    anchor.setRow1(0);

    double scale = 0.11;
    //Creates a picture
    Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
    //Reset the image to the original size
    pict.resize(scale);
}

fos = new FileOutputStream(absolutePathToIndexJSP);
System.out.println("file written");
workbook.write(fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

From what you're asking, you basically just want to delete the old file and create a new one each time, right?

If you're not concerned with possible collisions (two users attempting to download the same source location at the same time) then you could use [this delete file method](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-delete-file-in-java/) to delete the file and then create a new one. So, where you have

> new File(absolutePathToIndexJSP)

You should instantiate that, call the delete method, and then use it.